# Trying to rowspan table dynamically and save the data and table structure in the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

I am trying to create a table from a database.

The problem is that the user needs to rowspan some lines.

On some columns, for example,
column one has no rowspan, but columns two has to rowspan dynamically.

If you have 10 rows on the first columns and the goal is to manage to do merge by two or three rows according to the user's needs.

After that everything must the saved into the database, the content of the table and the structure, so when loaded must show like it was before.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM 8d_d4 where id_8d=". $_SESSION["id_8d_reclamacao"];
    $contarow=0;
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $rowd4_conteudo) { ?>
        <tr>
            <?php $colunas=0 ?>
            <td>
                <?php echo $rowd4_conteudo['como_ocorreu_problema'];?>
            </td>
            <?php $colunas=1 ?>
            <td ROWSPAN=<?php echo 1?>>
                <input style="border-width: 0px"  type="text" size=100% name="1porque[]" id="1porque" value=""/>
                 <input type="hidden" name="1porque8dd4_id[]" value="<?php echo $rowd4_conteudo['id'] ?>" />
            </td>

            <?php $colunas=2 ?>
            <?php if($contarow==$linha && $colunaalvo==1 && $coluna==$colunas){?>

            <td ROWSPAN=<?php echo $rowspan?>><input style="border-width: 0px"  type="text" size=100% name="2porque" id="2porque" value="rowspan==2"/></td>
            <?php } if($contarow<$linha && $colunaalvo==1 && $coluna==$colunas) {?>
                <td><input style="border-width: 0px"  type="text" size=100% name="2porque" id="2porque" value="rowspan<2"/></td>
          <?php   }
                   if ($contarow>$linha+$rowspan-1 && $colunaalvo==1 && $coluna==$colunas) {?>
                <td><input style="border-width: 0px"  type="text" size=100% name="2porque" id="2porque" value="rowpsan>2"/></td>
          <?php   } ?>
```